# Accounts disappearing on Samsung S3

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, accounts, bugs

I have developed an application which creates an account in "Account & Sync"

Some users on Samsung Galaxy SIII report that this account occasionally disappear (maybe at each reboot).

Of course, this doesn't happen with other phones.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, ie an account disappearing?

Comment: Voting to leave open, since the question also relates to users that are having issues with paid apps and their accounts being removed on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like the bug introduced in Android 4.1 Jelly Bean that (probably due to DRM and encryption) will install any paid application to `/mnt/asec`, even if it contains an account service.  This has a side-effect of having all accounts associated with such apps being removed on every reboot.  This [Google Code issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34880) has more details.

As of Android 4.2.1, it looks like the issue has not been resolved.  Many developers resort to creating a [second "JB work-around"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=jb%20workaround&c=apps) app that is free, and therefore can be properly installed and is able prevent the accounts of the main app from disappearing on reboot.

Comment: I forgot to mention this was the paid app version. You're pointing to a bug that is likely to be the one I'm facing. Thanks a lot, I had no way to test this myself. I just couldn't reproduce on the emulator...